# Magento2.2.5 multisite customer dashboard white screen

Tags: magento2, multistore, multidomain

Magento 2.2.5
I have a multi-site where I have 2 storesviews each one using there own domain name.

Now I have also in the admin panel in configuration customer configuration set share customer accounts = global I then cleared cache re-deployed etc. However when a customer tries to login on one website they get to there dashboard page no issues. however when I go in the other store view (domain) and login I am then just presented with a blank white screen.

When in the index.php file I enable errors I see the below

```
Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php 
on line 291
```

The server has plenty of ram and processor power. So IDK what the cause is?